# Lottery Guess Program Counter JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Created a lottery number guesser sort of program that takes a number 1-10 and has the user guess the number, a total of 3 times, to win a "prize". In the lottery part of the program, I was able to get no problem but can't get the program to count the number of guesses and display the correct prize amount.

**Here is the code I have:**

```
<script>
   var randomNum1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
   var randomNum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
   var randomNum3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
   console.log(randomNum1);
   console.log(randomNum2);
   console.log(randomNum3);
   console.log(x);
   var firstNum = false;
   var secondNum = false;
   var thirdNum = false;
   var x = 0;
   var moneyWon = 0;

   firstNum = parseInt(prompt("Guess the first number."));;
   secondNum = parseInt(prompt("Guess the second number."));;
   thirdNum = parseInt(prompt("Guess the third number."));;

   if((firstNum == randomNum1) || (firstNum == randomNum2) || (firstNum == randomNum3))
   {
       firstNum == true;
   }
       if(firstNum == true)
       {
           moneyWon = 100;
           x++;
       }
       else{
           moneyWon = 0;
       }

   if((secondNum == randomNum2) || (secondNum == randomNum1) || (secondNum == randomNum3))
   {
       secondNum == true;
   }
       if(secondNum == true)
       {
           moneyWon = 200;
           x++;
       }
       else{
           moneyWon = 100;
       }
   if((thirdNum == randomNum2) || (thirdNum == randomNum1) || (thirdNum == randomNum3))
   {
       thirdNum == true;
   }
       if(thirdNum == true)
       {
           moneyWon = 500;
           x++;
       }
       else{
           moneyWon = 200;
       }



        
   alert("The computer's numbers are " + randomNum1 + " " + randomNum2 + " " + randomNum3 +
   "\nYour guesses were " + firstNum + " " + secondNum + " " + thirdNum +
   "\nYou got " + console.log(x) + " right" +
   "\nYou've won $" + moneyWon);
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't need to tell you what are the errors and what are causing them, as my friend Dejan already included them in his answer. In my answer, I am trying to implement his answer as well as some useful javascript methods which may make your work a lot more easier and faster as well.

First of all, arrays are your friend. I have made arrays for user inputs as well as random numbers and populating them using a for loop.

Next, as we are using arrays, we can use the `includes()` method to find the values among the random numbers. It reduces your if else conditions.

Next, I am using string interpolation to get the output message.

```js
let randoms = [];
let nums = [];
let numbers = ["first", "second", "third"];
let winPrize = [100, 200, 500];
let losePrize = [0, 100, 200];

for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
  randoms.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1));
  nums.push(parseInt(prompt(`Guess the ${numbers[i]} number.`)));
}

let x = 0;
let moneyWon = 0;

for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
  if(randoms.includes(nums[i])){
    x++;
    moneyWon+=winPrize[i];
  }else{
    moneyWon+=losePrize[i];
  }
}

alert(`The computer's numbers are ${randoms[0]}, ${randoms[1]} and ${randoms[2]}. \nYour guesses were ${nums[0]}, ${nums[1]} and ${nums[2]}. \nYou got ${x} right. \nYou've won $${moneyWon}`);
```

I believe that if we follow such practices, our code will remain short as well as easily readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

First thing im noticing:

```
You got " + console.log(x) + " right" +
```

You dont want the `console.log()` here, just the `x`

The second thing, you dont want to set `moneyWon` every time in the `if`s, but rather do `moneyWon += amount`, just like you are doing with the `x`

Also, in the `else` (indicating the guess was incorrect), you dont want to set nor add to the amount (I would suggest deleting these 3 `else`s altogether):

`else{ moneyWon = 0; }`

and a minor thing - give meaningful names to properties, ie
`var firstNum = false` should be more like `(is)firstNumberGuessed` (the `is` indicates that this is a boolean

I see you are on the right track re this, but its good to learn not to be lazy about this stuff asap

EDIT: you can also throw out assigning true to firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum and just have this:

```
if((firstNum == randomNum1) || (firstNum == randomNum2) || (firstNum == randomNum3))

       {
           moneyWon += 100;
           x++;
       }
```

Comment: Finally, I guess you dont know or are not too experienced with arrays - when you get to know them better, think about refactoring the above using arrays - and i will give you a hint - use the array.includes method